# Compile multiple files internal module into one file AMD module

Tags: typescript

I have internal typescript module, this module is spitted into few files.

a.ts

```
/// <reference path='_all.ts' />    
module A {
  // some code
}
```

b.ts

```
/// <reference path='_all.ts' />    
module A {
  // some code
}
```

_all.ts

```
/// <reference path='a.ts' />
/// <reference path='b.ts' />
```

Is it possible to compile this module into one file and make it amd module?

Generally speaking, how can I "import" internal module into the external? For example when I'm trying to add new file export.ts:

```
/// <reference path='_all.ts' />
export module B {
   //some code that using module A
}
```

And feed export.ts to tsc, it compiles it to export.js amd module but doesn't include "A" module code at all.

**EDITED**
Example: https://gist.github.com/artemkozlov/8550165

Answer (score 0):

To compile to a single file use the `--out FILE` command line argument.  This will combine all *internal* modules into a single file.  To compile all *external* modules as AMD use `-m amd`.  In both cases you'll also want `-d` because that will generate a declaration file to go with it to reference from other projects.

It's not possible to compile multiple internal modules and produce a single external module.  see [12790262/how-to-spread-module-across-multiple-amd-files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12790262/how-to-spread-module-across-multiple-amd-files).

Comment: soo `tsc a.ts b.ts --out out.js -m amd -d` should work?

Comment: Yes that would generate a single js file and a file ```out.d.ts``` which you could reference in other projects.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. But it seems it doesn't work as I'm expecting. It doesn't generate single output file. Here is what I'm doing and what I'm getting as a result https://gist.github.com/artemkozlov/8550165

Comment: I misunderstood the question and my answer wasn't actually helpful.  I'll revise.